# Is windows partition manager reading ubuntu partition correctly?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, partitioning, ssd

It's been a very long time since I dual boot, I'm a linux user, asked to partition a laptop at work, to install ubuntu and keep windows 10. I did that, gave 50gb of ssd to ubuntu, that's where I installed `/` and 490 gb of hdd and thats where I installed `home`

So after partitioning `Y` is the ssd where ubuntu should have been installed

As you can see, Ubuntu has renamed the partitions where it has been installed but `Y` is untouched and totally free, strange assuming that's where to root directory should go.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see the filesystem is "RAW". As Windows isn't able to tell how files are organized it can't tell you much of those 50 GB are utilized.

It's likely that you're using some form of ext or similar as the filesystem and Windows doesn't have drivers for those filesystems by default.

Comment: Windows can tell that there is a partition there, where exactly that partition is on the disk, and how big it is. But that's it. There's no simple way to let Windows even read almost any type of Linux partition. That's how it has been since the beginning, with no sign of it changing any time soon.

Comment: However, many Linux distro's come with the ability to read/write the popular windows partitions with NTFS and whatever the latest FAT format is, including Ubuntu.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 - I use [Ext2FSD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/) on Windows and it happily detects and reads my Ubuntu `ext4` partition. It doesn't show in disc management, but it is accessible as `U:` (what else?) in Explorer and `cmd`. There is write support, but I have not used it enough to be sure of its reliability, and I have organised things so that I don't need it.