# How to tell which is Linux partition by looking at the partition manager

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, partitioning

[In the past, windows 10 used to say "Raw" for a Linux partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1289987/is-windows-partition-manager-reading-ubuntu-partition-correctly)

I had manjaro, I need to reinstall Linux, it's in the D drive, either the 50GB partition or the 62 GB portion, if another small partition got created for swap, I need to delete that as well.

I need to leave that partition unallocated so that it's easy to identify it from Linux installation side, I tried to identify it from there, couldn't do that.

[image]

I tried diskpart, it's my first time using it, so not sure how to use it but I didn't see anything special

[image]

Also, what exactly is that in volume 4? Why does it look stranger than the others?

Comment: Volume 4 is the Windows Sandbox base image. (Disk 3 in Disk Management.)

Comment: Use a partition manager outside windows, on a linux live image. It will be a lot more useful and clear than using windows' disk manager.

Answer (score 0):

Disk management can't determine Linux partitions. It can only identify native windows file systems (NTFS, FAT32). Partition managers in linux like (gParted and command line fdisk) are more powerful. Still you can use `diskpart` to select a partition to determine its type and check if it is GPT or MBR and then check if it is Linux partition.